# Why do people sit outside Primark Oxford Street West?

Tags: uk, london

I once thought they were waiting for the bus. I see people from different nations sitting there, any specific reason? I refuse to believe they are sitting for the sake of sitting.

Edit: to be clear, I am asking if this huge amount of people who sit there all the time are using the place as cafe, sitting there just watching other people do their shopping.

[image: Primark]

[image: Primark2]

Comment: I used to live near there; it's because the shop windows are designed such that they are convenient to sit on and the nearest place to sit down like this is the Wallace Collection. I have sat there also.  There is no secret to it. Lots of people shopping and they want to take a break, it could be Herald Square or Quai de la Tournelle or any other heavy pedestrian area

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/61106/discussion-on-question-by-ulkoma-why-do-people-sit-outside-primark-oxford-street).